# MYSQL Duplicate entry '0' for key Primary'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to move a MYSQL database from one computer to another.
I did a dump file on the computer with the database, I created the database on the second
computer and duplicated the table definitions and checked it make sure they are the same many times. When I use Load data infile I get the duplicate'0' key primary error.
I am using Windows 10 pro MYSQL 5.7.9

Answer (score 1):

This error might indicate that the table's PRIMARY KEY is not set to auto-increment.

Solution:

Check that there is a PRIMARY KEY set on your table, and that the PRIMARY KEY is set to AUTO-INCREMENT.

Comment: I found the answer I used mysql -u root -p database name < "path and filename" 
 Make sure the path and filename are enclosed in Double Quotes!! 
I could not get the load data infile to work always got the duplicate key error.